# Applying generics to java.util.Function

Tags: java, generics, lambda

```
Function<Map<?,List>,Integer> countMap = (Map)->{
    Integer count = 0;
    for(Object key:Map.keySet()){
        count+=Map.get(key).size();
    }
    return count;
};
Integer test = countMap.apply(containedAssets);
```

I get the compiler error : `apply(java.util.Map<?,List>> in Function cannot be applied to java.util.Map<java.util.String,List<myClass>>`. Is this sort of operation just disallowed with Function? I tried a different bit of code without the Map, just using a list, and Java had no trouble taking any type of list.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: consider changing to `Function<Map<?, ? extends List<?>>, Integer> countMap `

Comment: As a side note, just because the function returns `Integer`, you don’t have to use `Integer` for local variables inside the function. You can just use `int` as it’s enough to box the final result rather than boxing every intermediate result. Further, never iterate over the keys to call `Map.get` for every mapping when you can just [iterate over the values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks what you want is to create a function that will return the sum of the size of all the list's size contained in a `Map<K, List<V>>`.

In that case, you could have

```
ToIntFunction<Map<?, ? extends List<?>>> function = 
    map -> map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

We can use [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) as a function returning an integer, instead of `Function<...,Integer>`. Then, the rest of your method can be written a more simple way with the Stream API: get the values of the map, map each of those value to an `IntStream` consisting of their sizes and sum the element together.

Comment: It can even be a `? extends Collection<?>` instead of a list, since `.size()` comes from collection

Answer (score 5):

You've declared your `Function` to take a `Map<?,List>` where the type `List` is raw.  However, from your error message, you've passed a `List<myClass>`.

Declare your `Function` with the type parameter `List<myClass>`, i.e. following normal Java naming conventions:

```
Function<Map<?,List<MyClass>>,Integer> countMap = (map)->{
```

Because only `size()` is called, the `Function` doesn't care what type parameter the `List` is, so to make it more flexible, you can replace it with `? extends List<?>`, as has been mentioned in comments.

```
Function<Map<?, ? extends List<?>>, Integer> countMap = (map)->{
```

Comment: Or `? extends List<?>` if the type is not known.

Comment: As only list size is involved, `List<?>` is possible.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard You're right, your option can be used more flexibly.  I'll edit.

Comment: If we are at it, you don’t even have to insist on the objects being `List`s, `? extends Collection<?>` will do as well…

Answer (score 4):

As you don't care about map key type, and list type, you can declare your function as follows:

```
Function<Map<?, ? extends List<?>>, Integer> countMap;
```

It means: take a map where key is of *any* type and value type is any class extending list of *any* type, and produce `Integer` value.

And I'd suggest another way to get total size of lists, simply as:

```
countMap = m -> m.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```